# Xcode variable coloring

Tags: xcode

When I'm typing out new instance variables, they appear white.  To turn them green, I do a space/backspace between the semicolon.  Is there an XCode secret to automatically going through all of my classes and recognize the variables it has missed?

Something similar happens with the orange #define variables used throughout code too.

[image: colors screenshot]

UPDATE: This problem appears to be solved in xcode 3.2 with snow leopard.

Comment: Not fixed for me. Xcode still fails at life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this for a single file I usually select all text, cut, and paste it (cmd-A, cmd-X, cmd-V).

Make sure you've saved the header file with the instance variable first.

Comment: This is far easier than whitespacing through variables.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is rather fail that way. I hope they fix this in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile. That seems to get it for me :)

Best I can tell, it updates its text analysis during compilation.